# Low bandwith OLE DB destination, SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I have package which pulls data from CUBE(ADO net source) and loads the data to data warehouse (OLE DB destination- MS SQL 2012).

In the development environment wherein OLE DB destination is localhost-MS SQL 2012- 100% data is downloaded but when I change the destination to point to data warehouse. partial data is downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Do you recieved an error message?

Comment: What does "partial data is downloaded" mean? Does the source remain the same when you change the destination to production? What table is it loading? Are there foreign key constraints on that table? Are there triggers on the table? We need more information, please click the Edit link and help us better understand the situation

Comment: I do not get any error message since DFT executes successfully

Comment: @billink c- yes source remains same. there is no constraints on tables- like keys , triggers etc..

Comment: giving example to understand the problem - when destination was localhost if X records loaded into destination, only X-Y records were loaded when destination is changed to prod. Please not as I stated above the source will remain the same